# How can I not update a specified cocoapods library by myself

Tags: cocoapods

Situation is this, I use `SDWebImage` three part `library`, but you know nothing is perfect, and so I find using `SDWebImage` will cause memory leak, the link prove me:[cause memory leak](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/issues/538)

So, I comment out all the code which using this method:`decodedImageWithImage` in `SDWebImage`'s `class`, and result is very glad, the `memory leak` go to very little.

But, you know, `cocoapods` manage the `SDWebImage`, if next time I initall `cocoapods`, the `SDWebImage` will update, so, how can I do not update `SDWebImage` when install `cocoapods`?

Comment: You can use a "clone" version on your Mac, where you modified the code the way you want, and load the local SDWebImage: `pod 'SDWebImage', :path => 'thePathToYourLocalModifiedClone/SDWebImage'`

Answer (score 0):

You can fork the repo for SDWebImage and then point cocoapods to your fork of the repo (updated as you see fit) rather than the official one:

`pod 'SDWebImage', :git => 'https://github.com/aircraft/SDWebImage.git'`

You can also use the above format to point to a specific branch, tag, or commit using the guide at https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#pod